# Flask Api with HTML giving Runtime error: cannot open image_file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, parsing, flask, flask-restful

I am using flask based api with html ui file. When i am trying to upload a pdf through html and it passes through my api.py file it gives run time error that no such file exist.

```
app.py File

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image_file = request.files["file_image"]

    print(image_file)
    nlp_model = spacy.load("nlp_model")

    docs = fitz.open(image_file)
    text = ""
    for p in docs:
        text = text + str(p.getText())

    tx_2 = "".join(text.split('\n')) 

    doc = nlp_model(tx_2)
    s = []

    for ent in doc.ents:
        s.append(ent)

    return  s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

HTML file

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Upload new File</title>
<h1>Upload new File</h1>
<form action="/predict" method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name="file_image">
    <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

Comment: Please show us the full error traceback!

Answer (score 1):

The form

```
<form action="/predict">
```

would send data to

```
@app.route('/predict')
```

You want one of those

```
<form action="/index">
<form action="{{ url_for('predict') }}">
```

Edit: I'm not sure what `fitz.open()` does but you are passing the string `'image_file'` to it. Not the actual file name, which would be `fitz.open(image_file.filename)`

Also, you may need to save the file to disk before passing its filename to fitz, but again, I don't know if this module requires that.

Comment: While this is a problem in the code it would not give that error message.

Comment: @app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST']) . This is being the final code which is used. I made a mistake of writing index while writing on the stack overflow. So now also i am getting the same error.